# SQL - duplicate all rows in a table for each date in a specified range

Tags: sql, sql-server

First time question here, I've been trying to solve myself for a few days without success, hoping someone here can help please?

I have a SQL table of products, prices, etc which I am trying to duplicate for each date in a range that I specify.

Here is the table:

| Product_ID | Product_Name | Unit_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Laptop | 400.00 |
| 2 | Keyboard | 20.00 |
| 3 | Monitor | 150.00 |

Below is the result I am looking to achieve (the start and end date will be specified in the query):

| Date | Product_ID | Product_Name | Unit_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 1 | Laptop | 400.00 |
| 01/01/2023 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.00 |
| 01/01/2023 | 3 | Monitor | 150.00 |
| 02/01/2023 | 1 | Laptop | 400.00 |
| 02/01/2023 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.00 |
| 02/01/2023 | 3 | Monitor | 150.00 |
| 03/01/2023 | 1 | Laptop | 400.00 |
| 03/01/2023 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.00 |
| 03/01/2023 | 3 | Monitor | 150.00 |

etc.....

I have tried a few different things (cross joins, recursive ctes) but I just can't seem to get it to work for my specific requirements.

Just to add, I am using MS SQL Server 2016.

Any help offered would be very gratefully received! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cross join for this. ie:

```
declare @start Date = '20230701';
declare @end Date = '20230731';

create table products (Product_ID int,  Product_Name varchar(20),   Unit_Price money);
insert into products (Product_ID,   Product_Name,   Unit_Price) values
(1,'Laptop',    400.00),
(2,'Keyboard',  20.00),
(3,'Monitor',150.00);

select d.theDate, p.Product_ID, p.Product_Name, p.Unit_Price
from products p
  cross join
(select top(datediff(d, @start, @end)+1) 
  dateadd(d, row_number() over (order by t1.object_id)-1, @start) as theDate
from sys.all_columns t1 
cross join sys.all_columns t2) d;
```

| theDate | Product_ID | Product_Name | Unit_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-01 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-01 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-02 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-02 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-02 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-03 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-03 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-03 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-04 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-04 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-04 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-05 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-05 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-05 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-06 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-06 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-06 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-07 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-07 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-07 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-08 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-08 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-08 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-09 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-09 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-09 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-10 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-10 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-10 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-11 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-11 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-11 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-12 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-12 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-12 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-13 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-13 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-13 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-14 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-14 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-14 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-15 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-15 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-15 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-16 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-16 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-16 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-17 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-17 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-17 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-18 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-18 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-18 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-19 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-19 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-19 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-20 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-20 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-20 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-21 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-21 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-21 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-22 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-22 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-22 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-23 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-23 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-23 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-24 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-24 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-24 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-25 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-25 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-25 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-26 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-26 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-26 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-27 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-27 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-27 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-28 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-28 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-28 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-29 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-29 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-29 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-30 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-30 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-30 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |
| 2023-07-31 | 1 | Laptop | 400.0000 |
| 2023-07-31 | 2 | Keyboard | 20.0000 |
| 2023-07-31 | 3 | Monitor | 150.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/57F9AfwP)

EDIT: Explanation on how it works. You pass start and end dates as variables. Using sys.all_columns (because it has enough rows for our purposes out of the box) we generate dates from start to end date. row_number() over (order by t1.object_id) -object_id is an arbitrary selected column- we get a sequence like 1,2,3....N and limit the rows using TOP( datediff(d, @start, @end)+1). For 2023\07\01 to 2023\07\02 it would be 2 as an example (TOP(2)). Then we use the value from row_number() which is 1,2, ..., N  in dateadd(d, row_number() over (...)-1  ,@start) thus generating dates from @start to @end inclusive.

Last we cross join that 'dates' returned from subquery with the products to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple way to generate a list of numbers you can use for a series of dates and it should be very performant - this example will return from today + 30 days:

```
declare @start Date = GetDate(), @end Date = DateAdd(day, 30, GetDate());

with
  t1(n) as (select n from(values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))n(n)), 
  t2(n) as (select 1 from t1 x cross join t1 y), /* up to 100 rows - expand if more range required */
  t(n) as (select top (DateDiff(day, @start, @end)) Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 from t2)

select DateAdd(day, n, @start) [Date], p.*
from products p
cross join t
order by [date];
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c7UNTkRk)